# Построение уравнения зависимости по данным из датасета

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

Нужно построить уравнение зависимости рейтинга компании от процента какао в шоколаде. Я решил сначала построить график, посмотреть, примерно прикинуть. Но меня встретило это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня появилось предположение, что никакой зависимости нет. Но мне бы узнать мнение экспертов

Код и первые 10 значений:

```
x = np.array([63., 70., 70., 70., 70., 70., 70., 70., 70., 70.])
y = np.array([3.75, 2.75, 3.  , 3.5 , 3.5 , 2.75, 3.5 , 3.5 , 3.75, 4.  ])
plt.xlabel('Процент какао')
plt.ylabel('Рейтинг')
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А причем тут график к выявлению зависимости между данными? Потому что красиво и математику учить не надо?
Есть строго и четко сформулированная задача -  выявление зависимости выборки одних данных от выборки других. В математике (а точнее в статистике и по наследству -  в machine learning) это называется выявление корреляционной зависимости. Есть четкие тесты, которые совершенно точно отвечают на вопрос. В зависимости от данных - это может быть и коэффициент Пирсона (ваш случай), коэффициенты Кендела, Спирмана и много других.

Более того, там еще можно и обосновать свое решение, т.е. сказать, а какова вероятность ошибиться в ответе.  Вот и применяйте эти решения для вашей задачи.
Работаете с Python -  так там расчет этих коэффициентов уже давно реализованы -  что в numpy -  функция corrcoef(x, y), что в scipy.stats -  функция pearsonr(x, y), что в Pandas - метод x.corr(y)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте рисовать через `Seaborn`, хотя можно и через `Matplotlib`, вы просто не подходящий вид графика использовали. Хотя может быть в ваших данных и нет сигнала, но по вашему графику это невозможно сказать.

В общем, попробуйте для начала следующее. Данных вы дали мало, но тем не менее даже по ним что-то рисуется:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.regplot(x=x, y=y)
plt.xlabel('Процент какао')
plt.ylabel('Рейтинг')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.kdeplot(x=x, y=y, fill=True)
plt.xlabel('Процент какао')
plt.ylabel('Рейтинг')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если не выходить за рамки `Matplotlib`, то можно было бы взять другой вид графика - рассеянный:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Возможно, что-то стало бы чуть более понятно. Но не так, как с теми графиками, которые я показал выше. Но хотя бы не так хаотично, как в случае `lineplot`, который вы фактически использовали, когда каждая следующая точка соединяется линией с предыдущей, что в данном случае не нужно и даже вредно, ибо только захламляет график.